Why is this Reflection.Emit code causing an AccessViolationException?
As a general rule, managed code is not supposed to be able to cause access violations.  That happens in native code or in unsafe code.  But somehow, with a bit of playing around with some Reflection.Emit code that looks like it should be too simple for anything to go wrong, I'm getting an access violation.
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace Repro
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = BuildType();

            var realType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
            var arr = Array.CreateInstance(realType, 10);
            var caster = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast")!.MakeGenericMethod(realType);
            var typedArr = caster.Invoke(null, [arr]);

            var sorter = realType.GetMethod("Sort")!;
            var sorted = sorter.Invoke(null, [typedArr])!;
            var bomb = ((IEnumerable)sorted).Cast<object>().ToArray(); //blows up here
        }

        private static TypeBuilder BuildType()
        {
            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new("MyAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MyAssembly");
            var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("MyType", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(ValueType));
            var field = typeBuilder.DefineField("field", typeof(int), FieldAttributes.Public);
            var extractor = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("GetField", MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(int), [typeof(int)]);
            var il = extractor.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            var enumType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeBuilder);
            var impl = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Sort", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, enumType, [enumType]);
            il = impl.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, extractor);
            var getMethod = typeof(MethodBase).GetMethod("GetMethodFromHandle", [typeof(RuntimeMethodHandle)])!;
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getMethod);

            var orderFunc = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "OrderBy" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, orderFunc.MakeGenericMethod(typeBuilder, typeof(int))); // call Enumerable.OrderBy(enumerable, extractor)
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            return typeBuilder;
        }
    }
}

Peel away all the reflection, and this is supposed to generate code roughly equivalent to the following:
using System.Linq;

struct MyType
{
   public int field;
   private static int GetField(MyType value) => value.field;

   public static IEnumerable<MyType> Sort(IEnumerable<MyType> values)
   {
      return values.OrderBy(MyType.GetField);
   }
}

//in Main

    var arr = new MyType[10];
    var sorted = MyType.Sort(arr);
    var bomb = sorted.ToArray();


But somehow on the bomb line, it throws an AccessViolationException.  I'd love to understand why, and how I can fix it.

There is a lot wrong with your IL.
You have defined an instance field.
var field = typeBuilder.DefineField("field", typeof(int), FieldAttributes.Public);

Then you define a static function, so there is no this.
var extractor = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("GetField",
    MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.Static,
    typeof(int), [typeof(int)]);

So Ldarg_0 returns the first parameter which is an int. Quite why you needed this parameter is not clear anyway, but if you have an instance field you need an instance to work with. Either define the method as an instance method, or add a typeBuilder-typed parameter, or define the field as static.
var extractor = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("GetField",
    MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.Static,
    typeof(int), [typeBuilder]);

Or
var extractor = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("GetField",
    MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.Instance,
    typeof(int), new[]{});


Quite what you are doing here with ldtoken and GetMethodFromHandle is really not clear. ldtoken is mean for loading a TypeHandle in order to get a Type object. You need ldftn instead, and you need to create the actual delegate using newobj. You've also defined a return type, when you are not returning anything.
Instead you'd need:
var enumType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeBuilder);
var orderFunc = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
    .Single(m => m.Name == "OrderBy" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeBuilder, typeof(int));
var funcType = orderFunc.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType;

var impl = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Sort", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, enumType, [enumType]);
il = impl.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldftn, extractor);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, funcType);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, orderFunc); // call Enumerable.OrderBy(enumerable, extractor)
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

You may want to cache the funcType delegate in a static field as show by @JeremyLakeman, as it's an open delegate (no instance and no capturing).

Guh.  Making the param type an int was a dumb mistake on my end as I tried to prepare a minimum repro case; I knew it was supposed to be the same as the output type.  The real issue was the function pointer.  Thanks for pointing out where I was getting it wrong and how to fix it!

Enumerable.OrderBy() doesn't take a method handle as an argument, I think you're missing how C# will implicitly create a Func<T,int> for you.
Perhaps you should instead try to generate code like;
struct MyType
{
   public int field;
   private static int GetField(MyType value) => value.field;
   private static Func<MyType, int> func;
   public static IEnumerable<MyType> Sort(IEnumerable<MyType> values)
   {
      return values.OrderBy(func ?? (func = new Func<MyType,int>(GetField)));
   }
}

Which, according to sharplab.io, should look like the following IL;
ldarg.0
ldsfld class [System.Runtime]System.Func`2<valuetype MyType, int32> MyType::func
dup
brtrue.s IL_001c

pop
ldnull
ldftn int32 MyType::GetField(valuetype MyType)
newobj instance void class [System.Runtime]System.Func`2<valuetype MyType, int32>::.ctor(object, native int)
dup
stsfld class [System.Runtime]System.Func`2<valuetype MyType, int32> MyType::func

call class [System.Linq]System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1<!!0> [System.Linq]System.Linq.Enumerable::OrderBy<valuetype MyType, int32>(class [System.Runtime]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [System.Runtime]System.Func`2<!!0, !!1>)
ret

Having the runtime throw an exception in the face of incorrect IL seems like the safest outcome. I don't know if your code example can be tweaked to produce an actual unsafe outcome.
